# How to extract text from string?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to extract `2` from the string in `cell C3` and return it as the result of the function in `cell E3`:

[image]

Probably `SPLIT` is the wrong approach here.

**Edit:**

I replaced the `2` with `s` because some approaches work for numbers but not for letters:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\d")*1
```

[image]

---

Following OP's edit

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,";(.*),")
```

[image]

Please read more about [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

Comment: Thank you, your approach seems to work for numbers but not for letters. The `2` is just a placeholder for any arbitrary text. I was hoping to find a way to extract text, not only numbers. Im gonna change my question.

Comment: It is numbers that you asked for. Please use more representative data.

Comment: I shouldv made that clear from the beginning. sorry, I need to extract words, not numbers

Comment: It works, thank you :-). Just a small addition: 1. I am using the european version of google sheets and 2. intern delimiter in my case was `:` not `;` so the right formula for my case is: `=REGEXEXTRACT(C3; ":(.*),")`

Comment: Correct. It always depends on one's locale.